# Jquery on window resize append one time error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem on window resize. I should to append one time on resize an element to anather div but it appedn more times. How can i fix it ?
Here you can find an example, **resize window more time and after that click on first div and you will see the problem** :

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var windowW = $(window).width();

console.log(windowW);
        if(windowW <= 670){
          
           $('.take').on('click touchstart', function(){
                var info = $(this).text();
                $('.add').append('<p>Inormation :'+info+'</p>');
                });

          } else {
            $('.add').empty();

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="take">Some information </div>
<div class="add"> </div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use window resize if you want to append it on click?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski i have an complex code and this is just an example. So i want to have a answer to my question.

Comment: you want to append element on click right

Comment: but only one time

Comment: @patelarpan yes on window resize.

Comment: if user click again then?

Comment: @patelarpan it should to append one time on resize

Comment: @CananauCristian on resize or on click?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski if you resize the window and click on it it should append the element

Comment: why do you want to resize? just check the width

Comment: @RyukLee as i said i want to have it one resize because if you resize the window you must to refresh the page and after tat your idea will work.

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the width before append

```
$('.take').on('click touchstart', function(){
  var info = $(this).text();
  var windowW = $(window).width();
  if(windowW <= 670){
    $('.add').append('<p>Inormation :'+info+'</p>');
  } else {
    $('.add').empty();
  }
});
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/2hfb9kc6/)

Updated

```
//Disapear when >= 680
 $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    if(windowW >= 680){
        $('.add').empty();
    }
});
```

[Check size want to disapear](https://jsfiddle.net/2hfb9kc6/1/)

Comment: if size is 680 it should to dessaper. Thats why i want to qrite it on resize. Your answer is on click but i want it on resize and after that click whats mean **after resize you click on** !